# Function (?) to be applied to pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Current situation. 
I don't know if my function is correct and how to "apply" to pd.Series.

Function:

```
def levels(row):
if row.between(0,3):
    return "basic"
elif row.between(3.01, 8.5):
    return "intermediate"
else:
    return "advanced"
```

My Series: test_result["Points"] looks:

```
    1            3.0
Book1            0.0
Maja             1.0
Michal.Faron     0.0
Solutions       10.0
Name: Points, dtype: float64
```

I have tried:

```
test_result['LEVEL']=test_result["Points"].apply(levels)
```

I want at the end additional column: LEVEL with strings based on if criteria within my function

Comment: I think map is a better use for your syntax. Try  test_result['LEVEL']=map(levels, est_result["Points"])

Comment: Alireza when I use your suggestion it is close and my result is:
 Points LEVEL
1 3.0 <map object at 0x000001E06D170D90>
Book1 0.0 <map object at 0x000001E06D170D90>
Maja 1.0 <map object at 0x000001E06D170D90>
Michal.Faron 0.0 <map object at 0x000001E06D170D90>
Solutions 10.0 <map object at 0x000001E06D170D90>

Comment: Put a list outside of map as in : list(map(....))

Comment: This is much better done with `pd.cut`. Right now your `elif` logic is a bit wonky, for instance 3.001 is included in the `else` clause though you probably wouldn't want that. Really you should define proper bins with consistent closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `row` is a float, and floats do not have `between` method. If you really want to use it you can convert it back to be a pandas series:

```
def levels(row):
    if pd.Series([row]).between(0,3)[0]:
        return "basic"
    elif pd.Series([row]).between(3.01, 8.5)[0]:
        return "intermediate"
    else:
        return "advanced"
```

Answer (score 4):

It will be quite slow if applied to a large dataset. Would suggest using mask or loc;

```py
df['level'] = 'advanced'
df.loc[3.01 <= df.points < 8.5, 'level'] = 'intermediate'
df.loc[0 <= df.points < 3.01, 'level'] = 'basic'
```

Should be a lot quicker.

**EDIT**

Oh, I thought that would work, but it doesn't. Use this instead;

```py
df.loc[(df.points >= 3.01) & (df.points < 8.5), 'level'] = 'intermediate'
df.loc[(df.points >= 0) & (df.points < 3.01), 'level'] = 'basic'
```

Comment: When I put this into my code i got:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().